# Messages printed at the wrong moment with putStr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char

main = forever $ do
    putStr "Give me some input: "
    l <- getLine
    putStrLn $ map toUpper l
```

I have been learning Haskell from learn you haskell. When i try to run this code it does not behave like it should.

```
l
Give me some input: L
abc
Give me some input: ABC
```

When i run this it doesn't print the string first and i can input. After providing some input, in this case `l` it returns me like this : `Give me some input: L`.

What it should do is, ask for input by printing `Give me some input:` and after putting the input it shall return the input in uppercase.

How can i fix this?

Comment: It might be a buffering problem. Try disabling buffering with `hSetBuffering` on stdin and stdout, see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Use `putStrLn` instead of `putStr` for your prompt?

Comment: @Michail, it works after setting it. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Michail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6564029/michail) points out, it is a buffering issue, which can be solved with [`hSetBuffering`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering) for `stdout`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    forever $ do
    putStr "Give me some input: "
    l <- getLine
    putStrLn $ map toUpper l
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to change the [buffer mode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:BufferMode) for the whole program, you can use [`hFlush`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hFlush) to do an extra flushing of the buffer exactly where you need it:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char
import System.IO

main = do
    forever $ do
    putStr "Give me some input: "
    hFlush stdout
    l <- getLine
    putStrLn $ map toUpper l
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char

main = forever $ do
    putStrLn "Give me some input: "
    l <- getLine
    putStrLn $ map toUpper l
```

The issue here is that `putStr` doesn't write a newline. And the output buffer only gets flushed on a newline.